# splitting string into an object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I have this String `result:tie,player:paper,computer:paper`

I guess you could split into arrays and make a object and parse it an object, however this does not seem to be a good approach.

How would I get this String as a object?

```
let string = "result:tie,player:paper,computer:paper"
```

Comment: You should just split on `,` and then split on `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular string, I'd turn the string into proper JSON by surrounding the keys and values with `"`s, and then use `JSON.parse`:

```js
const string = "result:tie,player:paper,computer:paper";
const json = '{' + string.replace(/(\w+):(\w+)/g, `"$1":"$2"`) + '}';
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Though, ideally, whatever *serves* you that string should be giving you something in JSON format, rather than forcing you to resort to a hacky method like this to deal with a broken input.

Comment: Accepting in 10 minutes, pure beauty

Comment: I am returning a buffer from a python script to a JS. Don't think the library I'm using for that supports JSON.

Comment: It's still an X/Y problem - probably good to research (or ask) how to do the conversion python-side, it seems odd that a library that outputs objects wouldn't provide any ability to output a generic serialized object (that is, JSON format).

Comment: On side note: Nice trick but this will fail in case if key is containing non word character `xyz@123: some value`

Comment: @JonasGrønbek Can you clarify if the object can contain non-word properties/values, or `:`s or `,`s that aren't part of the key-value separators?

Comment: It cannot, it's spot on :)

Answer (score 2):

Split on `,`, iterate through, and split each string on `:` and make an object key/value property based on that. Use destructuring for simplicity:

```js
let string = "result:tie,player:paper,computer:paper";
let obj = {};
let propsArr = string.split(",");
propsArr.forEach(s => {
  var [key, value] = s.split(":");
  obj[key] = value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on the `,` to get key:value tokens, split those by `:` to get the key and value, and add them to the reduced object that collects the key value pairs.

```js
var temp = "result:tie,player:paper,computer:paper";

var obj = temp.split(',').reduce((result, token)=>{
  var [key, value] = token.split(':');
  
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```